js not connecting to html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style-index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
</head>

in javascript is:
alert('test')
external js is not connecting to html
structure: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1027105980900708442/1232712295893827635/image.png?ex=662a744a&is=662922ca&hm=5e90d125df3525f31584806fbdc41e91941442f596890bd8c0266e4ab76ca4b4&
edit: I also tried to rename project folder to remove all spaces

please attach the document tree

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1027105980900708442/1232712295893827635/image.png?ex=662a744a&is=662922ca&hm=5e90d125df3525f31584806fbdc41e91941442f596890bd8c0266e4ab76ca4b4&

What does it say in the Network tab of your developer tools? If you see a 404 error when fetching the script.js file, then the file isn't being found.

Also (fyi) type="text/javascript" hasn't been needed on script elements for many years now.

removed type="text/javascript" doesnt help

in network it says 200 to all files (it is also files from pc so I think its not server or network issue)

I know, I added that comment as an FYI.

What does your console tab say? Any errors reported there?

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1027105980900708442/1232715532097290250/image.png?ex=662a774d&is=662925cd&hm=016c93f2b030d0f8b822c5fa86ee1d5b071d2858d612078df120979d510952d6&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=615&height=670

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1027105980900708442/1232715929729765439/image.png?ex=662a77ac&is=6629262c&hm=5905b28242815d739714ca129a9fcf26f7962fab4ddf206c9fbcd79d0caaefcb&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=582&height=670

Your ../js/script.js is specifying that your script.js is located outside of the folder your page is located, inside a js folder and a script.js inside of it, suggesting this structure

some folder

js

script.js


some inner folder

your HTML





Since script.js is not loaded, either it does not exist on that place, or some privileges are lacking. Most frequently this kind of problem arises when you moved things around and the relative path that was correct earlier is no longer correct. If that's the case, then a path of /js/script.js instead could solve your problem, as long as the js folder is inside the root folder.
Make sure the right privileges are allowed, your webserver allows the mimetype of Javascript files and the file exists.

the structure is the same as you showed

project

js

script.js


html

index.html






also tried /js/script.js


If you are not used any folder you can follow this script link: <script src="./your file name"></script>

if you are used any folder you can follow this script link:  <script src="./your folder name/your js file name"></script>



im using this structure https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1027105980900708442/1232712295893827635/image.png?ex=662a744a&is=662922ca&hm=5e90d125df3525f31584806fbdc41e91941442f596890bd8c0266e4ab76ca4b4&

main folder

js

script.js


html

index.html






moved index higher and write path as js/script.js but still nothing. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1027105980900708442/1232751883160911903/image.png?ex=662a9928&is=662947a8&hm=75f401bfe35e5ec5d9fe00b75a0f84d08e212b5043fef6dc5222cdda1d18709c&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1261&height=366 Btw css is still working (I removed ../ for it too)
